# v-text-field returns string after typing even though it has type number

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

```
<VTextField
                :value="addOnStartingPrice"
                solo
                outline
                reverse
                append-icon="attach_money"
                type="number"
                min="0"
                step="any"
                @input="$emit('update:addOnStartingPrice', $event)"
              />
```

I have something like this.

Question 1) as soon as i change the number or type in it, it throws number value correctly, but its type is String instead of number, so type check gets failed. How do I get it to return value as type:number?

Question 2) what exactly does `step="any" and min="0"` do? They don't work I guess, because i can type negative numbers too.

Answer (score 33):

Indeed vuetify returns string. As a workaround you can use [number modifier.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)

```
<v-text-field type="number" v-model.number="computedAddOnStartingPrice" />
```

And you can have a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
  computedAddOnStartingPrice: {
    get () { return this.addOnStartingPrice },
    set (newVal) { this.$emit('update:addOnStartingPrice', newVal) }
  }
}
```

As per the `step` attribute read [Html input step](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp).

And for `min` attr read [Html input min](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)

> You can also use [vuetify rules](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#examples) to check if the user has entered a positive number. Example:

```
    <v-text-field
      type="number"   
      step="any"
      min="0"
      :rules="[numberRule]"
      v-model.number="computedAddOnStartingPrice"
    ></v-text-field>
```

The `numberRule`:

```
  data: () => ({
    //...
    numberRule: val => {
      if(val < 0) return 'Please enter a positive number'
      return true
    }
  })
```

[See it in action](https://codepen.io/Roland1993/pen/bXWGWm)

Comment: I can't have v-model. I am using :value prop. could it be done as :value.number? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes you can have v-model. Remove the `:value`, add a v-model and a computed property as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input v-model.number="price" type="number">
data() {
    return {
      price: '',
    }
  },
```

will save integer

Answer (score 1):

Just convert in to `Number` in `@input` handler.

```html
<VTextField
  :value="addOnStartingPrice"
  solo
  outline
  reverse
  append-icon="attach_money"
  type="number"
  min="0"
  step="any"
  @input="$emit('update:addOnStartingPrice', Number($event))"
  />
```

Comment: I did this, too. As it seems impossible to force accepting input of only numbers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

#### The [issue lies here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3a9fdc292af97c98be91c014bde1fac40a96e865/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.ts#L424) as the value property of InputElements is string.

And it gets [casted](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3a9fdc292af97c98be91c014bde1fac40a96e865/packages/vuetify/src/components/VStepper/VStepper.ts#L69) when needed

---

One thing you can do is "fix" by extend/override:

```
import * as comps from "vuetify/es5/components";

...

const override = comps.VTextField.extend({
  onInput(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    if (this.type !== "number") this.internalValue = target.value;
    else {
      this.internalValue = target.valueAsNumber;
    }
    this.badInput = target.validity && target.validity.badInput;
  }
});
Vue.component('NewVTextField, override);
```

---

Or "workaround" by `$emit(+$event)`, as this seems to be the [intended](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3a9fdc292af97c98be91c014bde1fac40a96e865/packages/vuetify/src/components/VStepper/VStepper.ts#L69) path

---

But i guess you should use the setter, getter aproach - as you can also chain validators in the setter

check: [@roli loli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57276012/11204469):

> ```
> computed: {
>   computedAddOnStartingPrice: {
>     get () { return this.addOnStartingPrice },
>     set (newVal) { this.$emit('update:addOnStartingPrice', newVal) }
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `v-on:change` Event to convert my input. I wasn't able to get
[Andrew Vasilchuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57277798/14251170) to work.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="item.quantity"
    label="Quantity"
    type="number"
    v-on:change="item.quantity = parseFloat(item.quantity)"
></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Number()` constructor to your model and it should works fine.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const mymodel = ref(0)

function apiCall() {
  const req = {
     size: Number(mymodel.value)
     // rest of request...
  }

  // rest of code...
}

</script>

<template>
  <v-text-field type="number" v-model="mymodel"/>
</template>
```